# Node app keeps redirecting to routes incorrectly

Tags: node.js, express

**Background**: I am making a node app which follows REST conventions. It's a simple app which allows authenticated users to post pictures of cats, which are displayed on the index page.

**Problem**: When the user clicks a button to add a new cat, this code runs :

```
router.get('/cats/new', isAuthenticated, function(req,res) {

    console.log('went to /cats/new');

    res.render('new', {user: req.user});
});
```

However, the user never gets to the `new` page because this code runs too:

```
router.get('/cats/:id', function(req,res) {

    var id = req.params.id;

    Cat.findById(id).populate('comments').exec(function(err, cat) {

          if (err) {
              console.log('entering get /cats/:id');

            console.log(err);

        } else {

            console.log('no errror yet');

            console.log(cat.comments);

            res.render('show', {cat:cat});

      }
      });
});
```

I dont understand why this is happening, I looked at the button responsible for rendering `new`, and it seems fine ; `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/cats/new">Add new cat</a>` .

If I change `router.get('/cats/new..')` to simply `cat/new` , this error goes away.

The same thing happens when I try to edit details about a cat. The route below is supposed to run and redirect the user to `user` page:

```
router.put('/cats/:id', function(req,res) {

    console.log('beginning /cat/:id');

    Cat.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id, req.body.cat, function(err, updatedCat) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);

            } else {

                console.log('------------ req.body.cat');
                console.log(req.body.cat);

                console.log('------------ updated cat');
                console.log('updated cat');
                res.redirect('user');
                console.log('not redirecting');
            }

        });   
});
```

However, the user goes back to `router.get('/cats/:id..)`. Infact, my console prints `not redirecting`.

To use put and delete requests, I am using `method-override`.

I am posting the entire routes file for `/cats/` below :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user.js');
var Cat = require('../models/cat.js');
var Comment = require('../models/comment.js');




//middleware
function isAuthenticated(req,res,next) {

    req.isAuthenticated() ? next() : res.redirect('/login');
}

router.get("/", function(req,res) {

    res.redirect("cats");
}); 

router.get('/cats', function(req,res) {

    Cat.find({}, function(err, cats) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else {
          res.render('cats', {cats: cats});  
        }  
    });
});


router.get('/cats/new', isAuthenticated, function(req,res) {

    console.log('went to /cats/new');

    res.render('new', {user: req.user});
});

router.post('/cats', isAuthenticated, function(req,res) {

    console.log('went to post /cats');
    var name = req.body.name;
    var image = req.body.url;
    var owner = req.user.username
    var description = req.body.description;

    cat = new Cat({
        name: name,
        image: image,
        owner: owner,
        description: description     
    });

    cat.save();

    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else {
            user.cats.push(cat);
            user.save(); 

        }
    })

     res.redirect('cats');

    });



router.get('/cats/:id', function(req,res) {

    var id = req.params.id;

    Cat.findById(id).populate('comments').exec(function(err, cat) {

          if (err) {
              console.log('entering get /cats/:id');

            console.log(err);

        } else {

            console.log('no errror yet');

            console.log(cat.comments);

            res.render('show', {cat:cat});

      }
      });
});


router.post('/cats/:id', isAuthenticated, function(req,res) {


    console.log(isAuthenticated);

    var id = req.params.id;

    Cat.findById(id, function(err, cat) {
        console.log('findById running');

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('err finding cat');
            res.redirect('/cats');

        } else {


            console.log('before Comment.create');
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment) {

                console.log('after Comment.create');
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);  

                } else {


                    console.log('right after 2nd else');

                    comment.author.id = req.user._id;

                    console.log(req.user._id);
                    console.log(req.user.username);

                    comment.author.username = req.user.username; 
                    comment.cat = id;
                    comment.save();

                    console.log('after saving comment');
                    cat.comments.push(comment);
                    cat.save();
                    console.log('saved cat');


                    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {

                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);

                        } else {
                            user.comments.push(comment);
                            user.save();
                            console.log('saved user');
                        }
                    });

                    console.log(comment);
                    res.redirect("/cats/" + cat._id);                
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

router.get('/cats/:id/edit', function(req,res) {

    var id = req.params.id;

    Cat.findById(id, function(err, cat) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
             res.render('edit.ejs', {cat:cat});
        }
    });  
});


router.put('/cats/:id', function(req,res) {

    console.log('beginning /cat/:id');

    Cat.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id, req.body.cat, function(err, updatedCat) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);

            } else {

                console.log('------------ req.body.cat');
                console.log(req.body.cat);

                console.log('------------ updated cat');
                console.log('updated cat');
                res.redirect('user');
                console.log('not redirecting?');
            }

        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: try keeping the new route after the id route in route declarations.

Comment: Hi! what id route are you talking about? I read that routes with parameters should be after routes with no parameters.

Comment: In any case, I tried your suggestion and kept the new route after all the id routes and it didn't work. The same problem persists.